# Unable to Dereference Pointer to Use Value in If Comparison

Tags: c++, pointers, logic, dereference

I am trying to compare a pointer to an int in my if statement for determining the output of logic gates. I know I need to deference the pointer to compare the actual value, but it's not working and I cannot figure out why. Any help would be appreciated.

```
bool TwoInputGate::getOutput(){
if(gateType == OR){
    if(input1 == 0 || input2 == 0)
        return false;
    else if(*input1 == 1 || *input2 == 1)
        return true;
}
else if(gateType == AND){

}
else if(gateType == XOR){

}
else
    return 0;
```

}

Below is the error I am getting: C:\Users\cplutchak\Documents\LogicGateProject\TwoInputGate.cpp:24: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('Component' and 'int')

Additionally this is how I am setting up my inputs:

```
void TwoInputGate::setInput1(Component* in1){
input1 = in1;
```

}

```
void TwoInputGate::setInput2(Component* in2){
input2 = in2;
```

}

Comment: What's `Component`, and what makes you believe it can be compared equal to an `int`? Prepare a [mcve]

Comment: Component is the base class with all pure virtual functions. TwoInputGate is my subclass to Component.

`class Component{
public:
    virtual void linearPrint() const = 0;

    virtual void prettyPrint(string padding) const = 0;

    virtual bool getOutput() = 0;
};`

Comment: So, what does it mean for an instance of `Component` to be equal to `0` or `1`?

Comment: I suspect you are looking for something as simple as `if(gateType == OR){ return input1->getOutput() || input2->getOutput();}`

Comment: So component is used as a pointer to the user inputs. If the first user input is 1 and the second is 0 I want to be able to determine the values by comparing whether or not they are equal to 0 or 1 and find the result of the logic gate.

Comment: @CheyennePlutchak can you post your code to pastebin?

Comment: @Jonathan here's the link for pastebin:

https://pastebin.com/KGMxBLcU

Comment: @CheyennePlutchak https://pastebin.com/tUfMQ5wU

Comment: So, given a `Component* in` pointer, how would you determine whether it's supposed to represent the user input of 1 or the user input of 0? `Component::getOutput()` method looks like it's meant for that, is it not?

Answer (score 0):

Your "input1" and "input2" are pointers pointing to the Component object.
Unless you have an "==" operator overloading for Component, it does not know how to use == with an integer value.

In c++, 0 is treated as false, and any other number than 0 as true. Using this logic you can simply write your function as following,

```
bool TwoInputGate::getOutput(){
    if(input1 == nullptr || input2 == nullptr){
        return false;
    }

    if(gateType == OR){
        return input1->getOutput() || input2->getOutput();
    }
    else if(gateType == AND){
        
    }
    else if(gateType == XOR){
        
    }
    else
        return false;
    }
}
```

If there are times when those input1 and input2 could not have been set to anything, then check for "nullptr" first before accessing the values.